# PHP & MySQL - Script won't allow mysql to work

Tags: php, mysql, session

im a beginner to php. But I had several websites before.

[my website with errors](http://a.taghabbo.tk)

I have a login.php file, and I think the error might be in that file. But when the user login for the first time, a change-password file will show.

I get no mysql, or php errors, which does this very difficult for me.

If its for help I got this error earlier, but I got rid of it:

> Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect
>   which existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session
>   extension does not consider global variables as a source of data,
>   unless register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality
>   and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or
>   session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively in Unknown on line 0

The problem is: when trying to log in the change_password.php file (which is included) show up, but when changing password, the mysql queries won't work. I have a table called login_log which is useful. I see login date, ip, username, password and access.

BUT its something wrong in my script, *username* won't be registred into *login-log*!

The number in the 'access' part is 0,1,2 and 3.

0: no access (failed login)
1: access
2: user is deactivated
3: first login

These mysql queries work, but not the other ones, thats what weird.
I'll send my files here, so you can take a look.

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
include("mysql.php");
include("rank.php");
$onlineusername = $_SESSION['username'];
$datoenidag = date("H:i");
$dates = time();

$quu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");

while ($log = mysql_fetch_array($quu)){
    $cash = $log["user_cash"];
    $user_rank = $log["user_rank"];
}

/*
$msg_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meldinger WHERE sett='nei' AND til='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$get_ant_msg = mysql_num_rows($msg_query);

if($get_ant_msg <= "0"){
    $message_img_link = "http://taghabbo.tk/v2/img/icon/new_02.gif";
    $message_ant = "0";
} else {
    $message_img_link = "http://taghabbo.tk/v2/img/icon/new_01.gif";
    $message_ant = $get_ant_msg;
}
*/

if(!empty($_SESSION['innlogget']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
?>
Logget inn
<?php
// if($user_rank == "Administrator"){
//    echo ('<div id="volter" style="margin: 3px;"><img src="/v2/img/icon/icon_82.png" style="width:20px;height:17px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:6px;" /><a href="/v2/admin/kontrollpanel">Kontrollpanel</a></div>');
//}
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['post_username']) && !empty($_POST['post_passord']))
{
    $post_username = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_username']));
    $post_password = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_passord']));

    $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '".$post_username."' AND user_password = '".$post_password."'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($if_hidden = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin)){
        $hidden = $if_hidden["user_hidden"];
        $first_login = $if_hidden["last_time_online"];
    }

    if($hidden == FALSE)
    {


    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $session_email = $row["user_email"];
        $b_navn = $row["user_username"];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $b_navn;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $session_email;

        if($first_login == TRUE)
        {

        $_SESSION['innlogget'] = 1;

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_online_status = '1' WHERE user_username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_time_user_ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' WHERE user_username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_time_online = '".$dates."' WHERE user_username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());

        echo("Velkommen ".$b_navn.",<br />vennligst trykk<br />");
        echo ("<h3><a href='/'>HER</a></h3>");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO login_log VALUES ('','".$_SESSION['username']."','$post_password','$user_ip','$dates','1')");

        }
        else
        {

        echo '<p style="color:whitesmoke;">Du har aldri logget inn før, for sikkerhetens skyld må du bytte passord.</p>';
        include("change_password.php");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO login_log VALUES ('','$b_navn','$post_password','$user_ip','$dates','3')") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_time_online='$dates',last_time_user_ip='$user_ip',user_online_status='1' WHERE user_username = '$b_navn'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO login_log VALUES ('','$b_navn','$post_password','$user_ip','$dates','0')") or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<b>Ukorrekt info</b><br /><a href="/">&laquo; Jeg har en bruker, pr&oslash;v igjen</a><br /><a href="/registrer">&laquo; Jeg vil gjerne registrere meg</a>';
    }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p style="color:whitesmoke;">Denne brukeren er deaktivert og kan ikke brukes.</p>';
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO login_log VALUES ('','$b_navn','$post_password','$user_ip','$dates','2')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    }
else
{
    if($page_login_error == true)
    {
        echo ('<p id="advarsel">'.$page_login_error.'</p>');
    }
    ?>
    Logg inn med brukernavn og passord. Hvis du ikke har en bruker, s&aring; kan du registrere deg her.
    <form method="post" action="" name="loginform" id="loginform" autocomplete="off">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <input type="text" name="post_username" class="loginandregister" placeholder="Brukernavn" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="password" name="post_passord" class="loginandregister" placeholder="Passord" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login" value="LOGG INN" /> eller <input type="button" class="register" value="REGISTRER DEG" onclick="location.href='/registrer'" />
    </tr></table>
    </form>
   <?php
}
?>
```

**change_password.php**

```
<?php

$newpass = $_POST["newpassword"];
$confirmnewpass = $_POST["confirmnewpassword"];
$pw_username = $_SESSION["username"];


if(isset($_POST['postPass']))
{

if($newpass != $confirmnewpass)
{
    echo '<p id="advarsel">Passordene er ikke like.</p>';
}
else
{
    $pw_query = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_password='".$newpass."' WHERE user_username='".$pw_username."'");

    if($pw_query){
        $_SESSION['innlogget'] = 1;
        echo '<p id="godta">Passordet ditt er endret!</p>';
    }
}

}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="password" name="newpassword" class="changepw" placeholder="Nytt passord" />
<input type="password" name="confirmnewpassword" class="changepw" placeholder="Gjenta nytt passord" />
<input type="submit" name="postPass" class="changepw" value="Fortsett" />
</form>
```

I hope you can see whats wrong. I thankful for answers.

> PS: if you want to take a look at the page; login credentials is:
>   username: Simen
>   password: VWbdc8NFby
>
> OR you can create your own user.

Comment: Have you start the SESSION ? (change_password.php)

Comment: Do the queries throw any error? btw make sure to **not** store passwords in plain text.

Comment: If the user logs in the first time and then submits the change passwd form, what happens then exactly? What is the control flow and the variable state? I assume there's probably a little mess?

Comment: I have start_session(); in change_password.php yeah. But nothing else happends.

Comment: `user_password` text NOT NULL,

Comment: this is my structure in "users" table, i have no type of encryption.

Every time i log in "access" is still "3", that means that every time i log in it is the "first time". I assume there is something wrong with the SQL code in login.php.

I get no errors.